# Swift / SpriteKit: How to create a water drop effect?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, shader, skspritenode

i wonder how the following effect could be made in Swift (SpriteKit).

[image: effect example image]

I think about adding some ShapeNodes and fill them with the background image with -yscale 1.

But i think this effect was made somehow different, because the background image isn't just mirrored horizontally - it also has some graphics effects on it (it is mirrored in the shape the water pearl has and so on).

Was it done with a ShaderNode?

Does someone has an idea how i could create a same effect in SpriteKit - like water pearls which looks like they are on the "camera" and they mirror the background "waterpearl like"?

Thank you.

Comment: This is generally done (in 2D) with distortion of a copy of the background, and the adding of a fake highlight and shadow. To the best of my knowledge, that's not the sort of thing that's available in SpriteKit, but is in Core Image.

Comment: Having said that, most of this could be achieved with the new SKWarp feature. Maybe.

Comment: Thank you Confused. Hm this sounds very complicated. I will try to program it somehow - i think this effect really looks cool. If someone else has a better idea please tell in the comments. :-)

Comment: Look into SKEffectNodes,  between that and SKCropNode, you should be able to achieve your effect

Answer (score 2):

Hmm well you could create a bunch of water images and have them displayed randomly on the screen at some z position, however I think this effect was made in another program like unity or something of the sort, Your best bet is to create transparent water droplets as images and have them displayed randomly on your screen.